# Reference redirection

Tags: c#, reference

I had an idea about which I couldn't find any direct syntax. I was wondering if it was possible to overload a reference type so that when it is referenced in a certain way it redirects its reference type into a new one.
I'd like to show an example about this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ICollection<int> CollectionProperty { get; private set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        this.CollectionProperty = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

This is just a simple class, but when MyClass is referenced, for example in a foreach, I'd like it to reference its inner collection like this:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
foreach(int item in instance)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

So here an item would be an int value of the class's collection's.

It was just something I was curious about, I don't know if it's even possible, maybe with some kind of reference overloading, or I don't know.
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Your `MyClass` could implement the interface `ICollection<int>` and redirect all interface members (manually) to `CollectionProperty`.

Comment: BTW: Although you call `CollectionProperty` a property, it is actually a member variable. (which is bad because it is public).

Comment: Yes I think implementing ICollection<int> could be a solution to that. Thank you!
And yeah I forgot the getter, I am editing it right now.

Comment: As a big rule, strong typisation is your friend. Do not try to fight it. Without it, we end up with the PHP or JavaScript cases from this Comic: http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/12/24/0747-melodys-guide-to-programming-languages/ If you just want to add a Array Access, just do so. Indexers are nothing but functions as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thank you, Christopher!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement IEnumerable in order to enable `foreach` functionality.

```
public class MyClass<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public List<T> Collection { get; set;}

    public T this[int index]  
    {  
        get { return Collection[index]; }  
        set { Collection.Insert(index, value); }  
    } 
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Collection.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public MyClass()
    {
        Collection = new List<T>();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var instance = new MyClass<int>();

        instance.Collection.Add(1);
        instance.Collection.Add(2);
        instance.Collection.Add(3);


        foreach(int item in instance)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1 2 3